# iOS 8: Where can I find a complete change log of iOS 8 compared with iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios8

I browsed developer.apple.com and tried Google "iOS 8 change log", but I can find one.

Any Idea?

If my memory is right, I do have seen such thing for iOS 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look in the "[What's new in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW1)" document that's right at the top of the iOS Developer page?

Comment: I found what I need is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014455, but this post do have helped me find API diffs, thank you.